# Firebird SQL: wildcard % with null values

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a smallint field that have some record have null values in that field. so when I use % in select only records have any values in that field are displayed.

I want to ask is there any other wild card character I can use to display all records including the ones have nulls ? or I have to use or is null ?

Thanks

Comment: Here's Firebird NULL Guide for your reference: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COALESCE function to replace NULLs with some predefined value. For example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  COALESCE(my_field, -1) = some_value
```

Comment: In this case it would be `... COALESCE(my_field, 'X') LIKE '%'`, rather than a numeric comparison.

Comment: This solution would work, but it wouldn't take advantage of existing indexes. Therefore, I would not recommend it. As a rule of thumb, it's always good to compare table fields directly, rather than converting them into something else.

Answer (score 5):

NULL has no value and can't be compared with other values, which explains why your query fails. If you want to fetch NULL values too, you have to add `OR your_field IS NULL` to your WHERE clause, as you already pointed out.

**Note**
Sometimes, NULLs can be confusing, especially for people who have just started with databases. A good way to keep in mind how NULL behaves is to think that its value is "*Something I don't know*". Then, when you'll write the query, you'll see that it makes sense that comparisons fail against NULL.

For example, "Is NULL greater than zero?" can be confusing. However, if you view the question as "Is something I don't know greater than zero?", it will immediately make sense: the answer is "I don't know" (and that's why the row isn't returned). :)